# Is there a way to use docopt to pass a vector of u8 from the command line?

Tags: rust, docopt

Is there a way to make the user prompt for the bytes inside brackets and separated by commas or something similar?

```
./main bytes [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I managed to make it look like this:

```
./main bytes 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

This is my code:

```
extern crate docopt;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

use docopt::Docopt;

const USAGE: &'static str = "
    Puzzle Solver.

    Usage:
      puzzle_solver string <text>
      puzzle_solver bytes [<bin>...] 
      puzzle_solver (-h | --help)
      puzzle_solver --version

    Options:
      -h --help     Show this screen.
      --version     Show version.
    ";

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Args {
    cmd_string: bool,
    arg_text: Option<String>,
    cmd_bytes: bool,
    arg_bin: Option<Vec<u8>>,
}

fn main() {
    let args: Args = Docopt::new(USAGE)
        .and_then(|d| d.deserialize())
        .unwrap_or_else(|e| e.exit());

    println!("ARGS: {:?}", args);
}
```

Comment: Do you know this https://github.com/TeXitoi/structopt? That's a really cool crate for command line arguments if you can use procedural macros (currently in nightly compiler).

Comment: @boiethios Could you give me an example that fits my needs using this crate?

Comment: This crate will not solve your particular problem, because as `docopt` (and as every other similar crate), it relies on `FromStr` to parse the input. But it is far more easier to use than the others. See the example.

Comment: I will post an answer. The solution to your problem is to implement `FromStr`

Comment: So the solution would be: take a String and make it a vector of u8?

Comment: Yep. You must create your own type `struct MyVec(Vec<u8>);` and implement `FromStr` for it.

Comment: @Boiethios: FYI, structopt doesn't require the nightly compiler! [Procedural macros were stabilized in Rust 1.15](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2017/02/02/Rust-1.15.html) :)

Comment: @JoeClay It seems that I missed some information :D

Comment: Do you understand that the command line is split into arguments by the shell, and not under docopt's control? Would `./main bytes "[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"` (with quotes) be acceptable?

Comment: Yes, I understand. With quotes would be acceptable of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but you have to implement `Deserialize` by hand.

`Vec<u8>` already implements `Deserialize`, and that implementation doesn't know about strings containing comma-delimited bracketed lists, nor does [`docopt::Deserializer`](https://docs.rs/docopt/0.8.1/docopt/struct.Deserializer.html), since the normal way to pass a list on the command line is element-by-element. So you have to make a new type that will deserialize from the format you want.

Naturally, you can also implement `Deref<Target = Vec<u8>>` and `DerefMut` for `Bytes`, if you want to treat it as a `Vec<u8>`. [Some people might consider this a slight misuse of `Deref`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086595/is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-implement-deref-for-newtypes), but it's probably fine in a situation like this.

```
extern crate docopt;
extern crate serde;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

use docopt::Docopt;
use serde::de;
use std::fmt;

const USAGE: &'static str = "
    Puzzle Solver.

    Usage:
      puzzle_solver string <text>
      puzzle_solver bytes <bin>
      puzzle_solver (-h | --help)
      puzzle_solver --version

    Options:
      -h --help     Show this screen.
      --version     Show version.
    ";

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Args {
    cmd_string: bool,
    arg_text: Option<String>,
    cmd_bytes: bool,
    arg_bin: Option<Bytes>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Bytes(Vec<u8>);

impl<'de> de::Deserialize<'de> for Bytes {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: de::Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        struct BytesVisitor;

        impl<'de> de::Visitor<'de> for BytesVisitor {
            type Value = Bytes;

            fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> Result<(), fmt::Error> {
                write!(formatter, "a bracketed, comma-delimited string")
            }

            fn visit_str<E: de::Error>(self, v: &str) -> Result<Self::Value, E> {
                let v = if v.starts_with('[') && v.ends_with(']') {
                    &v[1..v.len() - 1]
                } else {
                    return Err(E::custom(format!("expected a bracketed list, got {:?}", v)));
                };
                let values: Result<Vec<u8>, _> = v.split(",").map(|s| s.trim().parse()).collect();
                Ok(Bytes(values.map_err(E::custom)?))
            }
        }

        deserializer.deserialize_str(BytesVisitor)
    }
}
```

[Here it is in the playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=26bdd0598fe71ccb3ee067e86d4ce281&version=stable) These are the changes I made to get this to work:

1. Replace `[<bin>...]` with `<bin>` so docopt will know to look for a single thing and not a sequence of... things. (If you don't do this, docopt actually just throws you an empty string.)
2. Introduce the newtype `Bytes` wrapper around `Vec<u8>`.
3. [Implement `serde::de::Deserialize`](https://serde.rs/impl-deserialize.html) for `Bytes`. This entails creating a struct that implements the `serde::de::Visitor` trait, putting the code that picks apart the string inside its `visit_str` method, and passing the visitor to `deserialize_str`, which tells the `Deserializer` to expect a string and pass it to the visitor's `visit_str`.

I didn't realize it until almost done, but you could implement `visit_seq` instead, and make it parse `bytes [1, 2, 3]` (without quoting the list). But I wouldn't, because that defies command line convention; if you're using the shell to split the arguments anyway, you should go the whole way and just accept `bytes 1 2 3`.