# How to overload the reference operator?

Tags: rust, type-conversion

I've implemented `AsRef<[u8]>` for my type and the automatic conversion to `&[u8]` using `.as_ref()` works but the `&`-operator doesn't... how can I make the operator work?

```
struct Buffer {
    data: Vec<u8>,
}

impl AsRef<[u8]> for Buffer {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &[u8] {
        &self.data
    }
}

fn print_slice(slice: &[u8]) {
    slice.iter().for_each(|b| print!("{:02x}", b));
    println!()
}

fn main() {
    let buffer = Buffer {
        data: b"Testolope".to_vec(),
    };
    // print_slice(&buffer);     // <- This does not work
    print_slice(buffer.as_ref()) // <- This works
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:20:17
   |
20 |     print_slice(&buffer);
   |                 ^^^^^^^ expected slice, found struct `Buffer`
   |
   = note: expected type `&[u8]`
              found type `&Buffer`
```

I want a generic solution. Other datatypes like `Vec<u8>` support the conversion to `&[u8]` by using the `&`-operator. It would be cool if I could make this work for my own types so that I don't have to use `.as_ref()` every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot overload the reference operator, but you *can* hook into `Deref` coercion:

```
impl std::ops::Deref for Buffer {
    type Target = [u8];

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.data
    }
}
```

Your original code works in this case.

See also:

- [What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28519997/155423)
- [Is it considered a bad practice to implement Deref for newtypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45086595/155423)

Comment: This is what I was looking for; thanks for the links!

Comment: @Shepmaster, can you explain why after implementing as you show above calling `&buffer` is equivalent to `&buffer.data`? I would expect to have an error with `&buffer.data` because implementing deref returns the `data` field already, so it is essentially calling `(buffer.data).data`. See playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ebcece3fb7a076c5d8151e94e0c16f0e&version=stable&mode=debug

Comment: @MatthewStevenson 1. it's precedence is `&(buffer.data)` 2. deref coercion only kicks in at a [coercion site](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html) and field access isn't one of them, so `&((&buffer).data)` also works.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the whole struct with `print_slice(&buffer);` but only the `data` field with `print_slice(buffer.as_ref())`. If you make it `print_slice(&buffer.data)` it will work. Alternatively change the type signature of the `print_slice` function to expect `&Buffer`, which will make the `as_ref()` line not work.

Comment: Sry, my question was no clear enough: I want a generic solution. Other datatypes like `Vec<u8>` support the conversion to `&[u8]` by using the `&`-operator. Now it would be cool if I could implement this for my own types so that I don't have to use `.as_ref()` every time.