# Can I borrow a slice from a custom type?

Tags: rust

It's possible to borrow a `Vec<u32>` into either a `&Vec<u32>` or a `&[u32]`. I thought this was thanks to either the `AsRef` or `Borrow` traits. However, I was unable to implement such borrowing on my own custom type. Am I barking up the wrong tree here?

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

struct MyArray([u32; 5]);

impl MyArray {
    fn new() -> MyArray {
        MyArray([42; 5])
    }
}

impl AsRef<[u32]> for MyArray {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &[u32] {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl Borrow<[u32]> for MyArray {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &[u32] {
        &self.0
    }
}

fn main() {
    let ma = MyArray::new();
    let _: &[u32] = &ma; // compilation failure
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for [`std::ops::Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html):

> In addition to being used for explicit dereferencing operations with the (unary) `*` operator in immutable contexts, `Deref` is also used implicitly by the compiler in many circumstances. This mechanism is called ['`Deref` coercion'](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#more-on-deref-coercion). In mutable contexts, [`DerefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.DerefMut.html) is used.

Modified code:

```
use std::ops::Deref;

struct MyArray([u32; 5]);

impl MyArray {
    fn new() -> MyArray {
        MyArray([42; 5])
    }
}

impl Deref for MyArray {
    type Target = [u32];

    fn deref(&self) -> &[u32] {
        &self.0
    }
}

fn main() {
    let ma = MyArray::new();
    let _: &[u32] = &ma;
}
```

Comment: Related: [Is it considered a bad practice to implement Deref for newtypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45086595/155423).