# How can I implement traits for type aliases?

Tags: rust

I have some code like this:

```rust
type MyFn = Box<Fn(usize) -> bool>;

fn main() {
    let my_fn: MyFn = Box::new(|x: usize| x > 10);
    dbg!(my_fn);
}
```

This doesn't compile because `MyFn` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Debug`. That's reasonable, so what if I try to implement it for `MyFn`?

It fails saying:

conflicting implementations of trait `std::fmt::Debug` for type `std::boxed::Box<(dyn std::ops::Fn(usize) -> bool + 'static)>`

As well as:

only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types

How can I implement `Debug` and other traits for `MyFn`?

Comment: You can't MyFn is just an alias. Do something like https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=06b9086f9dff4485180f349f3aee1e09

Answer (score 4):

Creating a type alias does not create an entirely new type, it just allows you to refer to the existing type via a different name. Therefore, trying to implement `Debug` for `MyFn` is exactly the same as trying to implement it for `Box<Fn(usize) -> bool>` - which is not allowed, since your crate doesn't own the type or the trait. Rust's 'orphan rules' require your crate to have defined one or both for the implementation to be valid.

A common pattern to get around this is to create a 'newtype' struct, which wraps the type:

```rust
struct MyFn(Box<Fn(usize) -> bool>);
```

You *can* implement `Debug` for this struct, as the struct comes from your crate.

Comment: While this technically works, it makes calling the closure pretty awkward: `MyFn.0(...)`; this is a bummer.

Comment: @maxcountryman: It is possible to [implement `Deref`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6f7c164064905c2bd6533c1de66fdee3) to make this a bit cleaner, but [it's considered a bit of a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086595/is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-implement-deref-for-newtypes). Fingers crossed a nicer syntax for delegation gets added some day!