# Overloading AsRef<T> by using it to unwrap enums in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm using `AsRef<T>` and `AsMut<T>` to expose an wrapped value in an enum. Can anyone tell me if this is an anti-pattern? I came across [Is it considered a bad practice to implement Deref for newtypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086595/is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-implement-deref-for-newtypes), and it convinced me that `Deref` would be a bad idea, but I'm not sure about the approach below.

```rust
pub enum Node {
    Stmt(Statement),
    Expr(Expression),
}

impl AsMut<Expression> for Node {
    fn as_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Expression {
        match self {
            Node::Stmt(_) => panic!("fatal: expected Expression"),
            Node::Expr(e) => e,
        }
    }
}

impl AsMut<Expression> for Box<Node> {
    fn as_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Expression {
        (**self).as_mut()
    }
}

impl AsMut<Expression> for Expression {
    fn as_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Expression {
        self
    }
}

fn check_binop<T: AsMut<Expression>>(
    &mut self,
    sym: Symbol,
    lhs: &mut T,
    rhs: &mut T,
    ty: &mut Option<Type>,
) -> Result<Type, String> {
    let lhs = lhs.as_mut();
    let rhs = rhs.as_mut();
    ...
}
```

I'm considering just making my own traits (`AsExpr<T>` and `AsExprMut<T>`) that are just re-implementations of `AsRef<T>` and `AsMut<T>`. Functionally no different, but I think it would be clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suggest you do not do this, especially considering the docs for `AsRef` and `AsMut` say in bold:

> **Note: This trait must not fail.**

and I would definitely consider panicking to be failure. This isn't an anti-pattern so much as it is breaking the contract you opt-into by implementing those traits. You should consider returning an `Option<&mut Expression>` instead of going through `AsRef`/`AsMut`, or making your own traits like you mentioned.

Comment: Yep, this is definitely not fine. Too tired to answer a question, probably...

Comment: Thanks for validating. and very well put re: contract breaking. My original way didn't _feel_ right. I ended up going with my own `AsExpr`/`AsExprMut` which just mirror `AsRef`/`AsMut`. I tried `Option` and `Result`, but the ergonomics were really poor. Also, in my case, a compiler frontend, `as_expr` should never be called on a Node that might not contain one. That would be an unrecoverable bug in the compiler, rather than user error.