# Is there a trait, or pattern that lets me configure a struct to behave like its wrapped value?

Tags: rust

I have a struct that wraps a value. For example:

```
struct PageSize {
   value: usize
}
```

I now want to pass this around, but use it as if it was its wrapped value. E.g.:

```
let home_size = PageSize { value: 100 }
let about_size = PageSize { value: 200 }

let average = (homesize + about_size) / 2
```

Arithmatic is but one example. Others could be length() or hour() on resp. a wrapped String, or wrapped DateTime.

Is there a trait, or pattern that lets me forward any method calls to its wrapped value? And that enables operators like arithmetic or logic on its wrapped number or boolean?

Additionally, I would like to take over the "behaviour" of the wrapped value. e.g. via a derive, macro or trait. Where currently I need to derive or impl Display, in order to display:

```
#[derive(Display)]
#[display(fmt = "{} bytes", value)]
struct PageSize {
   value: usize
}

println!("size: {}", PageSize { value: 100 });
```

I'd prefer to configure my struct so that it inherits this behaviour from the wrapped value. When the wrapped value can be Debug, PartialEq, Display etc etc, then I'd like my `PageSize` Struct to inherit this. Not sure if this is possible at all, though.

I'm pretty sure I've seen this mentioned in either a rust book or article, but I forgot the terms and names, and location. So I cannot find the concept. An unfortunate issue is that `Wrapped` and `unwrap()` and Boxed etc already have meaning in Rust, which makes searching harder.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can implement `std::ops::Deref` and `std::ops::DerefMut`, here is the docs for [deref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html)

Comment: The answer is so simple and obvious. Thanks!

Comment: @berkes Actually, this is an antipattern. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086595/is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-implement-deref-for-newtypes) or [this](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/anti_patterns/deref.html). TL;DR don't do it.

Comment: Using `Deref` you lose the context for your mathematical operations, this would let you do `*page_size + *flight_distance` for example.

Answer (score 0):

It's called [Newtype Pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#using-the-newtype-pattern-to-implement-external-traits-on-external-types) in Rust.

```rs
pub struct Bar(Foo);
```

Even better with [`derive_more`](https://docs.rs/derive_more/latest/derive_more/):

```rs
use derive_more::{Add, Display, Div};

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Display, Add, Div)]
#[display(fmt = "{} bytes", .0)]
pub struct PageSize(usize);

fn main() {
    let avg = (PageSize(1) + PageSize(2)) / 2;
    println!("{}", avg);
}
```

Comment: As pointed out in a comment to @Timmy's answer, using deref to "get through" newtypes is an antipattern.

Comment: @BlackBeans I was aware of that argument but I think it really depends how you would like to define your type. I hold the a similar opinion as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086595/is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-implement-deref-for-newtypes) in his conclusion. And I agree to remove the `Deref` part of my answer.

Comment: @BlackBeans I would like to add that I think "get through" newtypes should be at least ok for wrapped number as long as not wrapping arbritray self defined type. In an intuitionistic logic way, `PageSize` is a number in nature, PageSize ⊂ usize ⊂ Z+, it should be used transparently as `usize`.

Comment: in Rust, you want to create newtypes when you *don't* want total transparency, which, btw, you don't obtain by implementing `Deref`, because deref coercion is only done under specific circumstances. If you want transparency for certain aspects, you have to implement them yourself (not necessarily by hand, you can use a macro). I am currently working on a crate to ease that, as, unfortunately, I'm not aware of any very powerful crate that does this kind of things for you.

Comment: @BlackBeans Yes, I agree it would be much better if there is another specific syntax/crate to allow well-defined transparency. Please let me know you have any progress on that project.