# Is there an existing enum for a mutable slice | owned vec?

Tags: rust, vector, enums, slice

I have some structs which could either be given a mutable slice or a `Vec` to own. The best solution I've been able to come up with is to make a simple enum which can contain a slice or a `Vec` and then `Deref`s to a slice.

```rust
pub enum DataSource<'a, T> {
    Borrowed(&'a mut [T]),
    Owned(Vec<T>),
}

impl<T> Deref for DataSource<'_, T> {
    type Target = [T];
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        match self {
            DataSource::Borrowed(val) => val,
            DataSource::Owned(val) => val,
        }
    }
}

impl<T> DerefMut for DataSource<'_, T> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        match self {
            DataSource::Borrowed(val) => val,
            DataSource::Owned(val) => val,
        }
    }
}
```

This seems quite simple (even if it's [not recommended to implement `Deref` for your own types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45086999/2854284)) so I'm sure I'm not the first person to think of this.

Is there something like this already in the Rust std library, or is there a crate which provides it?

Comment: I think you'll have to do it yourself, but there is prior work: The standard [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) type is almost what you have but keeps an *immutable* and has different semantics in that the borrowed variant is *promoted* to the owned variant via `.to_owned()` when mutation is desired. The linked guidance against `Deref` is mostly to dissuade inheritance-seeking behavior, which this case is not.

Comment: deref on such struct look ok

Comment: I believe the reason this struct doesn't exist is because it's not that useful: `Cow` is useful when you need clone-on-write, but with mutable data you can always write.

Answer (score 1):

[`either::Either`](https://docs.rs/either/1.8.1/either/enum.Either.html) implements [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/ops/deref/trait.Deref.html) and [`DerefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/ops/deref/trait.DerefMut.html) if both sides deref to the same type.

Comment: This is subjective of course, but I would not use `Either` for this, are use it only when you need two types and there is completely no difference between their roles besides being two different types.