# Define a struct where only some fields can be defaulted

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a struct in Rust that requires some fields to be defined, but not others.

For instance, in the following example struct only `occupation` is an option. Therefore, I'd like to require both `name` and `age`, but `occupation` can default to `None` if it's not defined.

```rust
struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: usize,
    occupation: Option<String>,
}

// should compile
let person_a = Person {
    name: "A".to_string(),
    age: 42,
    ..Default::default(),
}

// should not compile because `age` is not defined
let person_b = Person {
    name: "B".to_string(),
    ..Default::default(),
}

// should compile
let person_c = Person {
    name: "C".to_string(),
    age: 42,
    occupation: "Software engineer".to_string(),
}
```

Is this possible in Rust?

I don't need to stick with this exact API. Other APIs, including macros, are acceptable.

Comment: Only if you provide custom constructors (or group all defaultable fields into one struct and impl `Default` only for it).

Comment: You can also use the builder pattern, and there exist crates that can generate the builder for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you describe:

```
// should not compile because `age` is not defined
let person_b = Person {
    name: "B".to_string(),
    ..Default::default(),
}
```

is not possible to achieve. A struct either implements `Default`, or it doesn't. The `..` [struct update syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#creating-instances-from-other-instances-with-struct-update-syntax) also only works for structs of the same type.

There are multiple options to achieve convenient syntax for the *semantics* that you describe though:

---

#### 1) Multiple `new` functions:

```rust
impl Person {
    fn new(name: String, age: usize) -> Self {
        Self {name, age, occupation: None}
    }
    fn new_with_occupation(name: String, age: usize, occupation: String) -> Self {
        Self {name, age, occupation: Some(occupation)}
    }
}
```

Usage Example:

```rust
let p1 = Person::new("a".to_string(), 1);
let p2 = Person::new_with_occupation("b".to_string(), 2, "o".to_string());
```

---

#### 2) The Builder Pattern:

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
struct PersonBuilder {
    // These fields can be pub or not, depending on your tastes.
    // If they are pub, you can use the .. syntax for this builder
    // instead of / in addition to the field setter methods.
    occupation: Option<String>,
}
impl PersonBuilder {
    fn occupation(self, occupation: String) -> Self {
        Self {
            occupation: Some(occupation),
            ..self
        }
    }
    fn build(self, name: String, age: usize) -> Person {
        Person {name, age, occupation: self.occupation }
    }
}
```

Usage Example:

```rust
let p1 = PersonBuilder::default().build("a".to_string(), 1);
let p2 = PersonBuilder::default()
    .occupation("b".to_string())
    .build("o".to_string(), 2);
let p3 = 
    PersonBuilder { 
        occupation: Some("o".to_string()),
        ..Default::default()
    }.build("c".to_string(), 3)
```

---

#### 3) A sub struct for the defaultable Fields + a `Deref` `impl`:

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
struct PersonOptions {
    occupation: Option<String>,
}
struct Person {
    options: PersonOptions,
    name: String,
    age: usize
}
impl Deref for Person {
    type Target = PersonOptions;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.options
    }
}
impl DerefMut for Person {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        &mut self.options
    }
}
```

Usage Example:

```rust
let p1 = Person { 
    name: "a".to_string(),
    age: 1,
    options: Default::default() 
};
let p2 = Person { 
    name: "b".to_string(), 
    age: 2, 
    options: PersonOptions { 
        occupation: Some("o".to_string()),
        ..Default::default()
    } 
};
println!("{:?}", p2.occupation); // works because of `Deref`
```

---

#### Summary:

| Approach | Advantages | Disadvantages | Recommended for |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1) `new` functions | Simple and readable. | There are lots of combinations for structs with many fields. Also, the order of the parameters decides the corresponding field, which can become hard to read, and annoying to refactor if a field is added. | Simple structs with few fields / initialization variants |
| 2) Builder pattern | Scales better than `1)` if you have many fields. | More boilerplate than `1)`, can lead to suboptimal code generation due to the moves of the Builder in the setter functions. | Complex structs with many optional fields |
| 3) `Deref` | Closest in syntax to what you wanted. | `Deref` is generally [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086595/is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-implement-deref-for-newtypes) for simple structs because it might be confusing to the reader. `DerefMut` can also lead to borrow checker issues because the whole struct is reborrowed, not just the accessed field. | Only if you have a good reason why 1 and 2 are impractical (I can't really think of one though). |

Comment: Note that the boilerplate for the builder pattern may be reduced by using one of the existing helper crates like [`derive_builder`](https://crates.io/crates/derive_builder)