# how to make external recursive type insertable to a HashSet

Tags: rust, hashset

I use https://github.com/dtolnay/clang-ast to parse the JSON produced by Clang representing an AST to be available as a Rust data type, specifically the `Node`. I'd like to insert the nodes from the tree (`Node<T>` is recursive structure) into a `HashSet`. I could not even insert the root note:

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;
use log::debug;
use std::env;
use serde::Deserialize;

pub type Node = clang_ast::Node<Clang>;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Clang {
    BinaryOperator(BinaryOperator),
    Other,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct BinaryOperator {
    pub opcode: String,
    pub range: clang_ast::SourceRange,
}

fn main() {
    env_logger::init();

    let json = std::fs::read_to_string("ast.json").unwrap();
    let node :Node = serde_json::from_str(&json).unwrap();
    let mut node_set = HashSet::new();
    node_set.insert(node);
}
```

this fails the compilation with:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `clang_ast::Node<Clang>: Eq` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:28:21
    |
28  |     node_set.insert(node);
    |              ------ ^^^^ the trait `Eq` is not implemented for `clang_ast::Node<Clang>`
    |              |
    |              required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
note: required by a bound in `HashSet::<T, S>::insert`
...
```

So, I tried to add the `Eq` and `PartialEq` implementations using (following some advice from [How to implement Eq and Hash for my own structs to use them as a HashMap key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31835647/11582827)):

```rust
impl PartialEq for Node {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.id == other.id
    }
}

impl Eq for Node {}
```

however this fails with:

```
error[E0117]: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types
 --> src/main.rs:8:1
  |
8 | impl PartialEq for Node {
  | ^^^^^---------^^^^^----
  | |    |             |
  | |    |             `clang_ast::Node` is not defined in the current crate
  | |    `clang_ast::Node` is not defined in the current crate
  | impl doesn't use only types from inside the current crate
  |
  = note: define and implement a trait or new type instead
```

How do I make this work ? Also, why does the language/compiler imposes such limit ?

Following the answers on [Implement foreign trait for foreign type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160995/implement-foreign-trait-for-foreign-type) does not really help because there are more pieces to the puzzle (implementing `Eq`, `PartialEq`, the `Hash` trait, dealing with the recursive nature of `clang_ast::Note<T>`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implement foreign trait for foreign type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160995/implement-foreign-trait-for-foreign-type)

Comment: Not really. Firstly because I'd like to get as concrete answer as possible. Secondly because `clang_ast::Node<T>` is a recursive structure which makes this a bit more complicated, I believe.

Comment: Recursive structs indeed complicates this, but there is not much to do with that. The linked answer is still the solution.

Comment: It might be on generic level, however I am at loss w.r.t. how to apply the wrapped type for the inner field of the wrapped type.

Comment: You can't. That's simple. You have to implement `PartialEq` manually.

Comment: Um, how do I do that exactly ?

Comment: I already implemented `PartialEq` for the `Node` (the wrapped type - as suggested below) however that does not solve the problem for the inner field of `Node<T>`.

Comment: Wrap them too (you can provide getters to do that easily).

Comment: How do I do that exactly ? It all sounds but easy to me.

Answer (score -1):

> How do I make this work ?

Define a newtype wrapper e.g. `struct Node(clang:ast::Node<Clang>)`.

<strike>, or implement the trait on `clang_ast::Node<Clang>` rather than just `clang_ast::Node`<sup><sup>1</sup></sup>.</strike>

> Also, why does the language/compiler imposes such limit ?

Coherence. There should be only one implementation of a trait for a struct (ignoring specialisation). Allowing crates to implement traits they didn't define on types they didn't define is an opportunity for conflicts and incoherences (where one dependency uses one implementation and an other library uses an other incompatible implementation) which could lead to unsafety if they interact with the same objects in different ways (e.g. a generic collection of some sort, like a hashset).

Here though per the [implementation coherence rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/implementations.html#trait-implementation-coherence) since `Clang` is a local type as long as there are no [uncovered types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/glossary.html#uncovered-type) appearing as one of *its* parameters it should be fine (I could not test this on the playground as `clang_ast` is to minor to figure there, but it works fine with `Box`).

In other contexts (like `Box`) *overlapping* can also be an issue, but here `clang_ast::Node` does not implement `PartialEq` at all, not even conditionally. Until that happens there's no issue.

---

[1]: incidentally you may want to report that the error message is misleading, since `Node` is a generic type I don't think it makes sense that Rust accepts this attempt. In fact I can not reproduce it, on the playground trying to `impl PartialEq for Box` fails with "error[E0107]: missing generics for struct `Box`".

edit: struct out the completely incorrect bits where I thought the coherence rules were less strict than they actually are (which is only the case for `Box`, `Pin`, and reference types).

Comment: Note that in the OP code, `Node` is a local alias for `clang_ast::Node<Clang>`

Comment: @Jmb uh you're right and apparently I got confused by the parameters in the implementation coherence rules (aka what the uncovered parameters are, covered parameters refer to the *trait*'s generic parameters not the *type*'s), and the fact that `Box` is a fundamental type and thus has relaxed coherence rules, which the documentation does state and I missed. Thus testing on the playground using `Box` failed me. One day I will learn not to test things with `Box`.

Comment: using `pub struct Node(clang_ast::Node<Clang>)` , the `PartialEq` trait can be implemented using `self.0.id == other.0.id` so that seems to do the trick. The wrapping however leads to compilation error "the trait bound `Node: Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied" and as a fresh comer to Rust this is where I hit the wall. It seems I will need to provide implementation of the `Deserialize` trait for the wrapped struct.

Comment: @Vlad maybe you could deserialise to a `clang_ast::Node` then wrap in a `Node` before inserting into the hashset, rather than immediately deserialize to a `Node`? (otherwise yes you'll have to implement `Deserialize` to delegate-and-wrap)

Comment: Note that you can probably `#[derive (PartialEq, Deserialize)]` and most other common traits you need on your wrapper struct.

Comment: `PartialEq` would require the wrapped type to implement it (which is the entire issue here) no? And `Deserialize` would also require `serde(transparent)` but you're right that it'd work without needing to implement it by hand.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Using `#[derive (Deserialize)]`  and providing implementations of `PartialEq` and `Eq` (empty) allowed me to progress one step further. Now I just need to provide implementation of `Hash` on the wrapped type it seems.

Comment: The `impl Hash for Node` works (not sure if `fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
 self.0.id.hash(state)}` is the right thing to do here, though) for this simple case of inserting the root node into HashSet.

Comment: For a bit more complex task, though, like collecting a set of nodes from the tree using recursive function (`fn get_nodes(node: &Node) -> HashSet<&Node>`), I need to access the items in the `clang_ast::Node<T>`, specifically `pub inner: Vec<Node<T>>` (it is a recursive structure) and pass them to the recursive function. Not sure what to do there - implement the `new()` method for the wrapped type that would accept `clang_ast::Node<Clang>` ?